# #!/bin/bash equivalent in windows / specify interpreter for executable script IN the script

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I don't really know which part of the described technology stack the behaviour i'm describing is actually a property of - linux, or bash/sh? but it does not really matter i guess.

Anyway, on linux, in a bash or sh shell, i can run a script marked as executable in the file system without specifying the interpreter on the shell or somewhere global, but right in first line of the file,
e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or even

```
#!/usr/bin/gcl -f
```

for a common lisp implementation.

Is there a general windows, powershell or cmd.exe equivalent to this?Specifically, specifying the interpreter/command line to run the script with in the script itself, rather than on the command line or in the windows registry.

If not, what are similar options? The most similar thing I know about are shortcuts. Is there something more similar?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows the file extension specifies, which programs is used to Interpret a script.
You can also specify the Interpreter like "cmd": `CMD /c "c:\temp\script.cmd"` or with Powershell: `powershell.exe script.ps1`

What you can do (in Powershell) is, to specify the Version, which is used to run the script. Use `#Requires -version 3.0` in first line and it will throw error on v4 cmdlets etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the file extension is a global setting, not bound to the script itself. I don't understand the part about specifying the interpreter, you mean, on the cli, when calling the script? The version thing i understand to only work if the interpreter for the script is powershell itself, the question is about all executable interpreters.

Comment: An example, where you Need to mention the interpreter is if you want to run a powershell script as a scheduled task.  - And yes, the `#requires'  statement is language specific to powershell, as i wrote.